# Finding Arc Length of a curve

Tags: calculus, integration

Okay so just now getting into this. It's a rather straight forward topic, but it seems that a lot of questions have a quick and easy way of being solved. I found where that definite integral in the end just becomes the original, but where if it were something like $x + 1$, it would become $x-1$. Here is an example.

$$\,y= \frac{x^3}3 + \frac1{4x} \ \text{ where }\ 1 \leq x \leq \,2$$
taking the derivative gives you
$$\,f(x)' = x^2 - \frac1{4x^2}$$
Then plugging that into the arc length formula you get
$$\int_{1}^{2} \sqrt{1+(x^2-\frac1{4x^2})^2}\,dx$$
After finally doing the algebra and the integral, it comes out to this
$$\frac{x^3}3-\frac1{4x}$$
from there we just plug in from $2$ to $1$ and we get our answer. Though the biggest thing to me was that it took a few minutes of work to get from the beginning to here even though the only thing that changes was we went from
$$\frac{x^3}3 + \frac1{4x} \rightarrow \frac{x^3}3 - \frac1{4x}$$
Is this a common thing to happen in the simpler arc length calculations? Is it something I should look for or should I always do the work to make sure I get the correct answer. If it is something that has rules I could follow it could save me quite some time. Anyways, I couldn't find anywhere else where someone pointed this out (not saying it hasn't been answered here) so I figured I'd just ask. Thanks!

Comment: i have under the squar root $$\left(x^2+\frac{1}{4x^2}\right)^2$$

Comment: ''doing the algebra and the integral'' is the hard work....and here you have some mistake. If you write what have you done we can help you. Anyway see: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%5Csqrt%281%2B%28x%5E2-1%2F%284x%5E2%29%29%5E2%29

Answer (score 3):

It's all a matter of rewriting to get a very simple integral:$$\begin{align*}\int_{1}^{2} \sqrt{1+\left(x^2-\frac1{4x^2}\right)^2}\,dx&=\int_{1}^{2} \sqrt{1+x^4-\frac{1}{2}+\frac1{16x^4}}\,dx\\[1ex]
&=\int_{1}^{2} \sqrt{x^4+\frac{1}{2}+\frac1{16x^4}}\,dx\\[1ex]
&=\int_{1}^{2} \sqrt{\left(x^2+\frac{1}{4x^2}\right)^2}\,dx\\[1ex]
&=\int_{1}^{2} \left|x^2+\frac{1}{4x^2}\right|\,dx\\[1ex]
&=\int_{1}^{2} \left(x^2+\frac{1}{4x^2}\right)\,dx\end{align*}$$